# How to redirect if is post edit or publish page?

Tags: posts, redirect

I want to redirect if page is edit.php or post-new.php and i write this function. But it doesn't work. It must work only 'post' post type.

```
add_filter('admin_menu', 'redirect');
function redirect() {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');

        $screen = get_current_screen();
        if( $screen->post_type == 'post' && is_edit_page() ) {
            wp_redirect('http://localhost/wordpress/');
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to achieve, using the `id` instead of `post-type` should do the job. Try this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_redirect_function');

function custom_redirect_function() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id == "edit-post" ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

References:

- [get_current_screen](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/)
- [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

Comment: It works for all custom post types. I want work only 'post' post type.

Comment: Does it work for 'post' post type?

Comment: No. Doesn't work :)